# How does listIterator work

Tags: java

```
LinkedList<String> names=new LinkedList<>();
ListIterator<String> iterator=names.listIterator();
```

then we can perform operations using `iterator.hasnext()`, `iterator.next()`, etc.

If `ListIterator` is an interface, how could we access methods on its reference variable iterator as interface should have only
abstract methods?

Does `names.listIterator()` returns object reference of some class? If so which class object reference it returns?  Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 5):

ListIterator is the type of the *reference*. The object to which the reference points will be of a class that implements the interface. In Oracle's implementation, the class is a private class nested in `LinkedList`, called `ListItr.`

Answer (score 3):

If you call `names.listIterator()` on an object, it returns an object that is **not** of type Iterator, but of a type that **does** implement the Iterator interface. Then you refer to it as an Iterator, because Java (like any good Object-Oriented language) allows Polymorphism, which means so long as you know that the object in question implements the methods of an Interface, you can refer to that object as a type of that interface.

Answer (score 2):

> Does names.listIterator() returns object reference of some class?

Yes. It is. It's of type  `ListIterator`

Here is the implementation of that method

```
 public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
        rangeCheckForAdd(index);

        return new ListItr(index);
    }
```

Where ListItr is a class defined inside LinkedList

```
private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
```

Comment: why have a method in Arraylist class, which returns an object of a class that implements ListIterator Interface.. it all looks complex..why cant we just have the next(),hasnext(),previous, hasprevious() methods defined in the Arraylist class itself?..im confused with this too...appreciate if you can clarify with this.

Comment: To keep the class simple. All the iterator related logic and code moved to a seperate private class.

Comment: @amar - The iterator methods are in a separate class from the list because you can have **more than one iterator for a single list object**.

Comment: @amar, Expanding on what Andy Thomas said:    Sometimes it is useful to have more than one iterator for the same list at the same time.  Each ListIterator has its own state, independent from the state of any other ListIterator that may have been obtained from the same list.